# Can I leverage "Create -> From Template" for my own application?

Tags: google-drive-api

My application handles an app-specific mime-type.

Is there a way to integrate my app/filetype into the Template gallery so that I can create files from templates of my own file type?

Answer (score 0):

Not at this point but this is an interesting idea so I have filed it so that it gets reviewed and prioritized by the team :)